# Why does a constructor which takes iterators require elements to be EmplaceConstructible?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, c++-concepts

I have seen requirements for a sequence stl containers in the Standard (n4296), 23.2.3/4 (Table 100) and have read that a constructor which takes arguments-iterators (X - container, i and j - input iterators)

```
X(i, j)
X a(i, j)
```

requires a container's element type to be EmplaceConstructible.

```
Requires: T shall be EmplaceConstructible into X from *i
```

I think that a constructor can be implemented through calling std::allocator_traits::construct (m, p, *it) method for each iterator in range (where m - allocator of type A, p - pointer to memory, it - iterator in [i; j), and there is only CopyInsertable concept for elements is required because only one argument is provided for copying/moving, whereas EmplaceConstructible concept requires element to be constructed from a set of arguments. Is there any reasons for that decision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CopyInsertable` is a binary concept - given a container `X` it applies to a single type `T`, which is required to have a copy constructor. However, `*i` is allowed to be a different type from `T`, as long as there is a way to (implicitly) construct `T` from `*i`:

```
  char s[] = "hello world!";
  std::vector<int> v(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
  // int is EmplaceConstructible from char
```

A (contrived) example where `T` is *not* `CopyInsertable`:

```
struct nocopy {
  nocopy(int) {}
  nocopy(nocopy const&) = delete;
  nocopy(nocopy&&) = delete;
};
int a[]{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<nocopy> v(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

Comment: s/implicit/explicit/. `allocator_traits::construct` is direct-initialization and will happily do explicit conversions for you, for better or worse.